# Redirect to Mobile Site using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need htaccess code to redirect the visitors to my mobile website

Desktop Website's URL is
desktop.mywebsite.com

Mobile Website's URL is
mobile.mywebsite.com

I don't want mobile users to view desktop website and desktop users to view mobile website.

Comment: Fine, go for it! And what is your question? Sorry, seriously: show your code so far and explain what it is that does not work, where we can help. If you did not even try yourself but just post the question here to have someone else do your work, then I suggest you have a try at google instead.

Comment: Question Updated!
I need code that I write in ..htaccess file.

Comment: You need to show some efforts of your own in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your website is running  a non-windows os  (like linux) do the following:-

In your root folder of your webserver there is a file called .htaccess (notice the dot at the begining of the filename). If there is no such file , create one  with your text editor .

1) If you want to move your visitors from a single webpage to another new single web page type the following at the top of the .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html
```

2) If you want to move an entire site , type the following top of the .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newsite.com/

 This will catch all traffic in your old site and redirect to the new site. Just make sure to upload the .htaccess file in ascii mode and NOT binary mode.
```

Note:- Just replace yoursite.com  and newsite.com  with your site namees and oldpage.html and newpage.html with your old webpage name and new webpage name respectively.